# Draw a line linking two user controls in WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to draw a line that links two user controls on the screen and then moves whenever the user controls move. I created a third user control called, say, ConnectingLine, and then added two dependency properties that point to the user controls.

I wrote code so that ConnectingLine has references to the source and sink user controls but now I have run into some issues:

- How do I figure out the position of the source and sink user controls? I am new to WPF and am baffled by the absence of a 'Position' property that will return a Point object. If I could get two Point objects then I could bind them to a Line inside ConnectingLine:

  `< Line
  X1="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=Source.X}" Y1="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=Source.Y}"
  X2="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=Sink.X}" Y2="{Binding ElementName=Me, Path=Sink.Y}"
  x:Name="Connector"
  Stroke="Black"
  StrokeThickness="4" MouseDown="Connector_MouseDown" />`
- How do I get ConnectingLine to move along with the user controls?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [Canvas](http://wpftutorial.net/Canvas.html). Every UI element placed on a canvas has attached properties like: Canvas.Left, Canvas.Top, Canvas.ZIndex.